# Adding an XYZ tile using PyQGIS in PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, openstreetmap, wms

I am trying to add a XYZ Open Street Map tile into my QGIS project, using PyQGIS. I am currently trying to use PyCharm to start with, to see if my script is running correctly. I have looked through various other questions but none have worked successfully so far. I have also tried to add the link with `%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D` instead of `{z}/{x}/{y}` but still no luck. The code works perfectly inside the QGIS Python Console but does not seem to run in PyCharm. My code is:

```
# Add Base Map
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
rlayer2 = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')

rlayer2.isValid()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer2)
print(QgsProject.instance().mapLayers())
```

But when I run the script, an error occurs as my other raster and vector layer is added, but the OpenStreetMap layer becomes invalid and is not added to my exported map, even though it tells me in the script that `rlayer2.isValid` (as can be seen below).

```
{'OpenStreetMap_9b914e8c_7637_411a_beea_397b7f36f2c8': <QgsRasterLayer: 'OpenStreetMap' (Invalid)>}
```

Wetransfer link - [1]: https://we.tl/t-RiNdhUOHrc

Comment: I have edited the question so that it contains a link to my full script through a wetransfer link.

Comment: Maybe some firewall/blocking? Does this work: `import urllib.request;req = urllib.request.Request("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/14/9975/8501.png", headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla'});response = urllib.request.urlopen(req);print("request threw no error")`.

Comment: I guess the problem isn't about the project not adding OSM layer. It is added to the project. The problem might be crs.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have replaced the code I used above to your script and it comes back in the console, 'request threw no error' but it is not added to the exported map nor printed in the console when I ask to print map layers in project. Is there another step/code that I would have to write, to add it to the QgsProject.instance?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I use the same code within a script in the QGIS python console and the base map is printed in that exported map. Both has the same crs - EPSG3857, so I am not too sure??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you stated, OSM layer is added to the project. I found a solution (it worked for my toy data) after some trial and error. Since I don't have your data, I cannot guarantee that it will work for you.

- Add `project.setCrs(vlayer.crs())` after `project = ...` (line 179)
- You can remove these lines:

  ```
  201 canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
  202 root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
  203 bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(root, canvas)
  ```

  and

  ```
  301 canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
  ```
- Then try different scales for `map` and `map2`.

  ```
  208 map.setScale(30000000) # I used 50000000 for my map shown in the image 
  ...
  303 map2.setScale(100000000) # I used 100000000
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added the piece of code you suggested after line 179 but only rlayer and vlayer is still added and not the base map. It still prints out the OpenStreetMap layer is 'invalid' whilst I print map layers (line 86). Have you got any more ideas?

Comment: It works on my computer. I don't know. Also try to remove some lines I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I've truncated many parts of your code and added a toy data. If you share (if not restricted), I can try to find a solution using your code and data. Meanwhile, I use VS Code in Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a way I can message you/send the script to your privately? I have removed the lines but still no successful unfortunately, so I think if I share my script with you, then that probably would be the best method! Thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: I have sent you an email back now Kadir.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I had to download a base map and use that instead. None other options seemed to work

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the URL without urlencoding of the parameters that QGIS is supposed to update:

```
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried that and it still prints invalid layer for some reason... Is it meant to be {z}/{x}/{z} or should the last {z} be a {y}? I have tried this also and still no luck.

Comment: That was a typo, thanks. Sorry, I don't know what else is wrong.

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway!

Comment: It works fine for me though. `rlayer2.isValid()` returns `True` and I can add the layer just fine with `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer2)`.

Comment: That is strange then. I am not too sure why it is not working for me then... for some reason it must say that rlayer2 is not valid, as it then prints a statement saying invalid layer.

Comment: I am on QGIS 3.16

Comment: Same as me too. I think I may try to make a new, simple script first to see if I can export a map that just has a simple raster layer on it, so then I can expand on it with my other script. Thank you anyway

Comment: I entered the lines without the `if` statement in the Python console directly.

Comment: It works within the QGIS python console for me, just struggling to get it working in PyCharm/in a python script outside of QGIS.